# How to return true when a user is over 40

Tags: javascript, arguments

This function takes a user object with a property of age. It should return true if the user is over 40 and false if the user is 40 or younger.

```
function isOver40 (user) {
  if (user > 40) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
```

This is my answer but is does no pass the criteria. Would someone babel to tell me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: where's the curly brace for end of function ?

Comment: You probably mean `if (user.age > 40)`

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/  Since we don't know what `user` is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the property and you can return the result of the check.

```
function isOver40(user) {
    return user.age > 40;
}
```

With a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
function isOver40({ age }) {
    return age > 40;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It was defiantly the .age that fixed it. :)

Answer (score 0):

when you pass an object, you have to access the object's properties, not the object itself. Say you have:

```
user { //javascript object
    name: "foobar",
    age: 25
}
```

your function should look like this

```
function isOver40 (user) {
    if (user.age > 40) {return true}
    else {return false} //you can just say return false here, as the else is not really needed
}
```

function call:

```
isOver40(user);
```

hope this helps